# Digital High with 3.3V and 1K resistor

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, resistors, schematics

I was wondering if it's necessary to add a 1KOhm resistor on a digital input that listens to HIGH signals (3.3V) or I can just feed the 3.3V to it without any protection.

I'm making a circuit to enable an IC that listens to HIGH(1) and LOW(0) signals so I added an SPDT slide switch that selects between 3.3V and GND. The question is if a series 1K resistor on either 3.3V or GND lines is necessary.

The schematic:
[image]

EDIT: New Circuit
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the switch is not a shorting type (most are break before make), the R1 1K resistor is not necessary (and could be harmful to noise margin if the value of R7 was too low relative to 1K), however you may wish to have a resistor between pin 9 and SEL of a few K to help protect the IC against ESD that could come through the switch.

Edit: Eg

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmvsr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact if you have the pulldown R7 you may not need the ground connection on the switch at all.

Comment: R7 is a 1K resistor to pull SEL down while the switch is sliding (so that SEL floating pin is pulled down). As for the ESD protection, you mean a 10K resistor in series with SEL and pin 9 of the IC?

Comment: @AminMansouri:  If R1 and R7 are both 1K, pin 9 will be held at 1.65 volts while the switch is moving.

Comment: I just edited with the new circuit, can you check please?

Comment: Looks fine to me.